# Jquery, image showing after change input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

Anyone can show me what is wrong with my code? It show picture after change input but still in first input

[It changes only first input everytime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW7xB.png)

Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  function readURL(input, data) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var blah = '#blah' + data;
        $(blah).attr('src', e.target.result);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

  $(".active_file").change(function() {
    var data = $(this).data('im');
    var img_div = '#img_div' + data;
    var img_id = '#image_id' + data;
    $(img_id).html('<img id="blah' + data + '" src="#" alt="your image" />');
    alert(data);
    readURL(this, data);
    data = data + 1;
    $(this).removeClass('active_file');
    $(img_div).after('<div class="col-md-2 img_div" id="img_div' + data + '" ><input form="formid" name="file" type="file" id="fileI" class="inputfile active_file" data-im=' + data + '><label class="col-md-12 image " for="fileI" id = "image_id' + data + '"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i><br>Nahrať obrázok..</label></div>');



  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">


  <div class="col-md-6 gallery">
    <div class="row galeria_row">
      <div class="col-md-2 img_div" id="img_div1">
        <input form="formid" name="file" type="file" id="fileI" class="inputfile active_file" data-im='1'>
        <label class="col-md-12 image " for="fileI" id="image_id1"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
          <br>Nahrať obrázok..</label>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a more complete code so we can re-produce the image you show ?

Comment: updated... that is full code of that section with pictures

Comment: correct you JS part .. remove <script> tag

Comment: done, it is okey now?

Comment: still not able to see it like the picture, there is no CSS ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zuktp3yb/ here it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use delegate event of jQuery because your DOM is being updated in real time.
So instead of doing:

```
 $(".active_file").change(function() {
```

do this

```
$(document).on('change', '.active_file', function(){
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


function readURL(input,data) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          var blah = '#blah' + data; 
            $(blah).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(document).on('change', '.active_file', function(){
  var data = $(this).data('im');
  var img_div = '#img_div' + data;
  var img_id = '#image_id' + data;
  $(img_id).html('<img id="blah'+data+'" src="#" alt="your image" />');
  alert(data);
    readURL(this,data);  
    data = data + 1;
      $(this).removeClass('active_file');
     $(img_div).after('<div class="col-md-2 img_div" id="img_div'+data+'" ><input form="formid" name="file" type="file" id="fileI" class="inputfile active_file" data-im='+data+'><label class="col-md-12 image " for="fileI" id = "image_id'+data+'"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i><br>Nahrať obrázok..</label></div>');



});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">


  <div class="col-md-6 gallery">
    <div class="row galeria_row">
      <div class="col-md-2 img_div" id="img_div1" >
        <input form="formid" name="file" type="file" id="fileI" class="inputfile active_file" data-im='1'>
        <label class="col-md-12 image " for="fileI" id = "image_id1"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
          <br>Nahrať obrázok..</label>
      </div>
      
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks my savior  :)  and i had problem in ids too
input : id="fileI" -> id="fileI + number"
label : for="fileI" - for="fileI + number" 

thanks again mate :)